# Spring 5 + Hibernate 5 : How SessionFactory is getting Autowired with LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

I am developing REST apis using Spring MVC 5.0.8 and Hibernate 5.2.11

I have created `AppConfig` class,in which I have created `getSessionFactory()` method with return type `LocalSessionFactoryBean`

```
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("saptarsi.auditdb.model");
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return factoryBean;
    }
```

And Inside `DaoImpl` class I have autowired `SessionFactory`

```
@Repository
public class LOcaldbDaoImpl implements LocaldbDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void getAllApiDetails(HttpRequestEntity<ApiDetailsFilterDto> requestEntityDto) {
    }

}
```

**And everything is working fine**

**But I want to know how SessionFactory is getting autowired.**

Because I am not returning `factoryBean.getObject()`,which is responsible to return `SessionFactory` type object.

And `@Autowire` will look for `SessionFactory` type in Bean factory.

So how **Autowiring** is happening ?

Answer (score 4):

Because after you initialized the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, the `buildSessionFactory` method was called. [Link to calling](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.java#L600).

```
protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sfb) {
    return (this.bootstrapExecutor != null ? sfb.buildSessionFactory(this.bootstrapExecutor) :
            sfb.buildSessionFactory());
}
```

After that, SessionFactory bean will be in the ApplicationContext.

Comment: can you explain me how `bootstrapExecutor` playing the role

Comment: You can read a description of purpose usage bootstrapExecutor in [Javadoc of sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.java#L381) . It is used for asynchronous initialization of SessionFactory.

Comment: Thanks,it was helpful

Answer (score 2):

All Spring beans was load in `ApplicationContext`. Try to read here more https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html

Comment: Thanks,it was helpful